# How to solve issues with file names with characters with accents on moving last folder's files?

Tags: batch-file, diacritics

I need to move to a new folder the last x files from a lot of folders

Structure:

```
Master Folder
    Subfolder_01
        Subfolder_01_File_0001.xxx
        Subfolder_01_File_0002.xxx
        ...
        Subfolder_01_File_0125.xxx
        Subfolder_01_File_0126.xxx

    Subfolder_02
        Subfolder_02_File_0001.xxx
        Subfolder_02_File_0002.xxx
        ...
        Subfolder_02_File_0356.xxx
        Subfolder_02_File_0357.xxx

    Subfolder_03
        Subfolder_03_File_0001.xxx
        Subfolder_03_File_0002.xxx
        ...
        Subfolder_03_File_0018.xxx
        Subfolder_03_File_0019.xxx
```

Result expected for the last 2 files:

```
Target_Folder
        Subfolder_01_File_0125.xxx
        Subfolder_01_File_0126.xxx

        Subfolder_02_File_0356.xxx
        Subfolder_02_File_0357.xxx

        Subfolder_03_File_0018.xxx
        Subfolder_03_File_0019.xxx
```

I wrote this code:

```
@echo off
Rem Enable accent for French name
chcp 850

Rem Set Console text color
color 0A

Rem Get master folder
SET "SourceFolder=%~1"
cd %SourceFolder%

Rem processing all subfolders
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /ad-h /b') DO (
    echo.
    echo; Processing Folder %%i
    cd %%i
        call :innerloop
    cd..
)

PAUSE
goto :eof

Rem get all last X (limit) files and move them to the target folder
:innerloop
setlocal
set /a "n=0, limit=2"
FOR /F "delims=" %%z IN ('dir /s /b /o-n') DO (
    echo Moving File %%z
    move "%%z" C:\Target_Folder
    2>nul set /a "n+=1, 1/(limit-n)"||goto :break
)
goto :eof

Rem stop when "limit" is reached
:break
goto :eof
```

It's working but with some issues.

1. The long folder/filename break the script and I have `a cannot find the specified path`.
2. Sometimes it's moving in the target folder the sub folder with all files in it.
3. Some other time the script jump out the master folder and try to process another master folder.
4. And I have some accents and special chars problems too. The `chcp 850` convert some accents `é` in `'` and break the script with a `cannot find the specified path`.

I tried `chcp 1252` but that convert all console accents `éà` in `úó` and do not solve the `é` converted in `'` and the `cannot find the specified path` issue.
I tried to save the script in ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-8 without BOM without any effect on this issue.

What to change in batch code to solve all those issues?

Comment: Thanks Mofi, for the corrections and precisions brought to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without explicit examples of the difficulties, we're reduced to theory.

change

```
cd..
```

to

```
cd %CD%
```

which will be replaced by the current directoryname at the start of the `for`, so the resultant directory will be explicit.

change

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%z IN ('dir /s /b /o-n') DO (
```

to

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%z IN ('dir /a-d /b /o-n') DO (
```

in case the directory-scan is encountering a directoryname (`/a-d`) - removing the `/s` removes the subdirectory scan - I don't know whether that's an issue.

Change

```
    move "%%z" C:\Target_Folder
```

to

```
    move "%%~sz" C:\Target_Folder
```

to perform the `move` using shortnames, which should overcome the accents problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solve most of my problems except the é interpreted in '. Strange thing it's if a replace the é with a new é it's working ??